# Laravel Queue: Undefined array key "job" when listen event from AWS SQS

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, queue, amazon-sqs

I have a service A that pushes data to the queue in AWS SQS.
At the same time, there is a service B that plays the role of listening and retrieving data from the queue in AWS SQS. Service B currently uses Laravel Queue to do this task. I have set parameters in env as below:
`.env`

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sqs
AWS_SQS_ACCESS_KEY=xxxxx
AWS_SQS_SECRET_KEY=xxxxx
SQS_PREFIX=https://sqs.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/xxxxx
SQS_QUEUE=xxxx
SQS_SUFFIX=
```

`config/queue.php`

```
'sqs' => [
             'driver' => 'sqs',
             'key' => env('AWS_SQS_ACCESS_KEY'),
             'secret' => env('AWS_SQS_SECRET_KEY'),
             'prefix' => env('SQS_PREFIX', 'https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/your-account-id'),
             'queue' => env('SQS_QUEUE', 'default'),
             'suffix' => env('SQS_SUFFIX'),
             'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', 'us-east-1'),
             'after_commit' => false,
         ],
```

And run `php artisan queue:listen`
When a piece of data is posted to AWS SQS, the Queue runs, but I get the error below:
[2024-03-02 08:41:49] local.ERROR: Undefined array key "job" {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined array key "job" at D: \Inico\Inisoft\Code\Welinko\wlk-user\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job.php:338)

I don't understand the reason, can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: Is service A using the same code base as service B? If it is not it might be pushing jobs in a format that the Laravel code in Service B can't recognise

Comment: @apokryfos Service A uses NodeJS, provided by another party.

Comment: The cause of the current error is that Laravel adds specific entries to the payload it sends to SQS and expects them to be there. You'd need to write an adapter to read the job from SQS and convert it to something that Laravel can work with. The current queue adapter for SQS is [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/10.x/src/Illuminate/Queue/SqsQueue.php#L131) which creates an `SqsJob` instance from what comes in the queue. You will also need to replace the existing [SqsJob](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/10.x/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/SqsJob.php) class with your own.